# Making a mosaic plot out of restaurant data

Tags: python, data-visualization, statsmodels

Simple enough but the formatting of the data is giving me a headache:

I have the sales data of items for each day of the week. Each row is a different item, and the number corresponds to how many is sold in that day.

I want to make a mosaic plot to see the distribution of item sales across days (so seven 'columns', one for each day). I'm using statsmodel.mosaic.

How should I reformat this? It's already a dataframe, and I'm using the mosaic(...) function.

```
0   Fri Mon Sat Sun Thu Tue Wed
0   2   3   3   1   2   3   4
1   2   2   0   1   1   3   1
2   0   0   1   0   2   0   2
3   4   1   3   0   6   1   4
4   0   1   0   0   1   6   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   14  8   13  9   14  25  40
7   3   11  4   4   5   7   7
8   16  24  20  18  22  32  41
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   1   8   6   1   0   8
11  0   1   2   2   3   4   3
12  10  5   3   7   11  13  22
13  3   10  2   5   6   6   15
14  5   4   7   7   12  10  17
15  0   6   0   2   1   3   3
16  1   0   0   1   8   2   6
17  3   6   7   4   7   15  24
18  0   0   0   1   1   0   3
19  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
20  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
21  6   3   2   4   10  19  14
22  2   5   4   2   4   12  9
23  7   6   5   8   12  9   11
24  0   2   0   0   0   2   2
25  0   2   0   0   1   3   1
26  0   2   0   0   0   1   0
27  0   0   0   0   0   3   0
28  5   0   2   3   1   2   5
29  0   0   0   0   0   0   1
30  0   0   0   0   0   0   1
31  4   4   2   0   5   7   4
32  2   3   4   1   7   3   5
33  1   1   1   0   4   2   2
34  0   0   0   0   0   0   1
35  1   3   3   3   8   6   13
36  1   2   0   0   2   6   6
37  2   5   0   3   0   7   2
38  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
39  1   2   2   0   0   4   3
40  1   4   0   3   1   8   5
41  2   1   2   1   2   1   3
42  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Would you specify what you mean by reformatting, please? Re-ordering columns?

Comment: To reply to me personally, type the 'at' character for a menu.

Comment: @BillBell Are you familiar with statsmodel.mosaic? All the data necessary for displaying the chart is there, though I am unsure why the format isn't working. The docs for the library are in a jargon I can't quite understand.

Comment: I have very limited familiarity with it. It would help me (and others) if you could show us the code you tried and give us an indication of what output you were hoping to get, or tell us what diagnostics you got.